# Is possible by jquery set value on attribute which name contains square brackets

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Lets say I have an Angular app with photo album. When user click on image, full size photo will show inside modal. Inside modal I need to dynamically change attribute [src] on img element when user click on picture.

```
<img [src]="" />
```

So inside script, after click it should be like this:

```
var $myelement =$("img");
$myelement.attr('[src]', 'http://google.com');
```

I tried many ways how set [src] attribute but without success result. How can I fix it, square brackets are needed.
Example above produce following Error: Uncaught (in promise): InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '[src]' is not a valid attribute name.

Thank you

Comment: Why did you put brackets around the src attribute ?

Comment: The [first result](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-an-element-by-an-id-that-has-characters-used-in-css-notation/) of googling "jquery selector escape special characters" would have answered your question by the way

Comment: After doing more testing, it seems that putting brackets around attribute names in HTML only causes trouble ...

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this `[src]` ?

Comment: Thanks for the upvote. Wat did you ended up using ? If my answer fixed your problem, you can mark it as "answer" so website knows that this question has been answered.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use

```
$myelement.attr('\\[src\\]', 'http://google.com');
```

Why do you put brackets around the src attribute ?
Is there a reason you don't simply write

```js
var $myelement =$("img");
$myelement.attr('src', 'http://via.placeholder.com/350x150');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="" />
```